# Ember Data: When does the "didLoad" event fire?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

[Ember Data's documentation discusses different events in a model instance's lifecycle](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/model-lifecycle/).
I would expect that the `didUpdate` event is triggered whenever any of a model instance's properties change. But my experiments don't show this behavior.

Here is a JS Bin example: http://jsbin.com/uziwam/9/edit
In that example, you can see that I register handlers on the "ren" model instance: I register handlers (`console.log(..)` messages) for the `didLoad` and `didUpdate` events.

When starting the code, "ren's" `didLoad` event fires, which is expected behavior. Then, when using the GUI to edit "ren's" properties, no `didUpdate` event fires. This is (at least for me) unexpected behavior.

What do I have to do to let the `didUpdate` event fire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `didUpdate` event is fired when the record has effectively been saved, that means that you have to commit it, and the your adapter has acknowledged the commit.

To commit the changes of the record, you can use record.get('transaction').commit().

see http://jsbin.com/uziwam/11/edit

If you want to commit the transaction when a property change, you can put an observer on it.

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr("string"),
  lastName: DS.attr("string"),

  firstNameDidChange: function(){
    this.get('transaction').commit();
  }
});
```

If you want to generalize against each record's attribute, you should be able to do something like:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr("string"),
  lastName: DS.attr("string"),

  init: function(){
    this._super();
    this.eachAttribute(function(attributeName){
      this.addObserver(attributeName, this, this.commitRecord); 
    }, this);
  }

  commitRecord: function(){
    this.get('transaction').commit();
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/uziwam/14/edit

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and working example! ... is there an easy way to have the transaction commit right at the moment a property has changed (... i.e. so that there is no need for a user-initiated `save` action)?